# How to get ID from URL

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am developing a Backbone Marionette web app.
I this app I got routes that look like this:

```
projects/:id/tasks
```

How can I get the ID of that route (URL)?

If I use this I get the whole URL:

```
Backbone.history.fragment
```

**Update**

This is how I define the routes for projects.

```
@Projectapp.module "ProjectsApp", (ProjectsApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    class ProjectsApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
        appRoutes:
            "projects/new" : "newProject"
            "projects/:id" : "showProject"
            "projects/:id/edit" : "editProject"
            "projects" : "listProjects"

    API =
        listProjects: ->
            new ProjectsApp.List.Controller

        newProject: ->
            new ProjectsApp.New.Controller

        showProject: (id, project) ->
            new ProjectsApp.Show.Controller
                id: id
                project: project

        editProject: (id, project) ->
            new ProjectsApp.Edit.Controller
                id: id
                project: project

    App.Router.on "route:newProject", (project_id) ->
        alert project_id

    App.commands.setHandler "new:crew:member", (region) ->
        API.newCrew region

    App.vent.on "project:new:clicked", (project) ->
        App.navigate "projects/new", true

    App.vent.on "project:tasks:clicked", (project) ->
        App.navigate "projects/#{project.id}/tasks", true

    App.vent.on "project:created", (project) ->
        App.navigate "projects/#{project.id}", true

    App.vent.on "project:show:clicked project:back:clicked", (project) ->
        App.navigate "projects/#{project.id}"
        API.showProject project.id, project

    App.vent.on "project:clicked project:edit:clicked", (project) ->
        App.navigate "projects/#{project.id}/edit"
        API.editProject project.id, project

    App.vent.on "project:cancelled project:list:back:clicked", (project) ->
        App.navigate "projects"
        API.listProjects()

    App.addInitializer ->
        new ProjectsApp.Router
            controller: API
```

Comment: Where do you want to access it ? Inside the callback method for the specific route ?

Comment: I want to access it when fetching new tasks.

Comment: Can you update the question with some more code showing where exactly the fetching of new tasks happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router will provide your handler function with the attributes parsed fro the URL.

You have a route defined with `"projects/:id" : "showProject"` but then your handler is

```
showProject: (id, project) ->
        new ProjectsApp.Show.Controller
            id: id
            project: project
```

They don't match: your router will send the parsed `id` from the URL, but that's it. You need to get the project on your own, before passing it to the view, e.g.:

```
showProject: (id) ->
        project = @projects_collection.get id
        new ProjectsApp.Show.Controller
            id: id
            project: project
```

Of course, this means you need to be able to access the project collection, or fetch the project, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A router should be defined similar to this (example):

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "page/:number":"go_to_page",
        "show_something":"show_something"
    },

});
```

Then, you can bind route events to a function that accepts the route variables, example:

```
Router.on("route:go_to_page",function(page) {
   // page parameter corresponds to :number in the url hash, so now you can query your models with this string.
});
```

Hope this example helps...

Comment: Ah cool, thanks. The reason I use project/:id/tasks is that a user clicks a project and then get a list of all the task belonging to that project. Is there a way to get the ID of the project?

Comment: yea, you can do something like (in your router):
`routes:{ "projects/:id/tasks":"do_something" }`
and then: `Router.on("route:do_something",function(project_id) { //project_id is what you need });`
Hope I understood your question correctly...

Comment: Updated my question. How can I use your solution with my code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with coffee script , but I think 
`App.Router.on "route:editProject", (project_id) ->
        alert project_id` 
Should work EDIT: Of course, change the alert function to whatever you need... From what I understand, your problem is getting the project id , right?